# How does negating work in quantified statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

What is the negation of “all users are online”?

**p(x) represents users online**

Answer: Not all users are online,
i.e. at least one user is offline.

Symbolically: ¬(∀x p(x)) ≡ ∃x ¬p(x).

**Hi I just wanted to understand how the negation of all users are online**

becomes ¬(∀x p(x)) ≡ ∃x ¬p(x).

**I thought If I negated the statement all users are online I would get just**

∃x ¬p(x).

**I really don't understand how their is a equivalence symbol in the negation**

Comment: In some conventions, only $\exists$ is part of the basic alphabet for writing statements, and $\forall x$ is defined as a shorthand for $\lnot\exists x\lnot$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\equiv$ is not meant to be part of the symbolization.

Rather, the provided answer is indicating that $\neg \forall x \ P(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\exists x \ \neg P(x)$

That is, if you start with negating the statement that 'all users are online', you get $\neg \forall x \ P(x)$ as an answer, but if they don't want the answer to start with a negation and have any quantifiers at the start, you can use the equivalence to change it into $\exists x \ \neg P(x)$

Answer (score 0):

I think the ≡ just means the left hand side is equivalent to the right hand side. Suppose statement A means for all x, p(x) is true. Then the negation of A is: there exist an x, such that p(x) is false. p(x) is false means the negation of p(x) is true. So the negation of A is also: there exist an x, such that the negation of p(x) is true.

Comment: So what I got as an answer is correct ∃x ¬p(x).

Comment: I think that is correct. And for every single user x (among all of the users), $p(x)$ probably should mean the one user is online, not the users (multiple users) are online.

Comment: To make this more precise, you can define the set of users (that are offline or online) as $X$. Then $\forall x \in X: p(x)$. You missed a colon. Some books use comma instead of colon.